# How can I punish certain outputs more than others in a keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have a keras model with multiple (8) output neurons, that all go through a softmax activation function. My dataset, which consists of around 300.000 datapoints, is however largely filled with data where just having the first output neuron at 1 and all the others at 0 allows the neural network to score a high accuracy. When fitting my model to the dataset, I get stuck at a 0.3 loss (when using mean squared error) and end up with a bad neural network, that doesn't work well on new data.

I would like to weight the error of every neuron very high, except for the one that lets the network score a high accuracy. In python/pseudo code, this would look like the following, where `y_true` and `y_pred` might be lists or numpy arrays:

```py
def some_error_function(...):
    # something like mean_squared_error()

def weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    # Regular loss value for the first output neuron
    loss = some_error_function(y_true[0], y_pred[0])

    # Loss multiplied by 100 for the other output neurons
    loss += some_error_function(y_true[1:], y_pred[1:]) * 100
```

Just to clarify, `some_error_function(...)` here could take single values as parameters or lists, so `y_pred[1:]` means passing a list or numpy array of every value except for the first one.

When compiling my model, how would I replace my current loss function with a weighted loss function like the one above?

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=<current loss function>)
```

I tried just passing a function like `weighted_loss`, but I wasn't sure how I can compute a loss with the given `y_true` and `y_true`, as they are of the type `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`.

Also I don't know what exactly I should return. When I returned 0.0 as a test, I received the following error:

```py
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['sequential/dense/kernel:0', 'sequential/dense/bias:0', 'sequential/dense_1/kernel:0', 'sequential/dense_1/bias:0', 'sequential/dense_2/kernel:0', 'sequential/dense_2/bias:0', 'sequential/dense_3/kernel:0', 'sequential/dense_3/bias:0'].
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a class imbalance problem.  There are a number of strategies to address this through sampling, synthesizing data, or subsetting.  You can't architect your way out of data problems.

Comment: So you're saying that even if I'm able to weigh my classes, it will probably not solve my problem? @James

Comment: Sorry, my last sentence was ambiguous.  If you have data problems, address the data problems first.  Trying to tweak your architecture at the start get you the best result, do so after you have addressed the data issues.

Comment: I tried weighting my parameters, and it didn't really work that well. Could you point me to some resources where I could read about sampling and subsetting? @James

Comment: https://medium.com/james-blogs/handling-imbalanced-data-in-classification-problems-7de598c1059f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `fit` method, there is a `class_weight` parameter used to give weights to each class (output neuron).

So, use it. Read the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)

> **class_weight:** Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

You want that dictionary like:

```
weights = { 0: low_weight, 
            1: high_weight, 
            2: high_weight,
            ....
            7: high_weight }
```